# How to convert array in localstorage to JSON that can be used to render elements into div?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, themoviedb-api

first i wanna apologize if my question isn't super clear..

howeverm i feel like i am close to figuring it out. what i wanna do is basically create a movie app *Without React* where you can favorite movies by basically clicking on the icon, it takes the ID from the movieDB API and pushes it into an array in localstorage

```
<a><i class="bi bi-bookmark" onclick="favMenu(${item.id})"></i></a>

function favMenu(movie_ID) {
    //SETTER
    faveArr.push(movie_ID)
    console.log(movie_ID)
    localStorage.setItem("favemovies", JSON.stringify(faveArr));

}
```

however, i am not succeeding at retrieving the movie posters into another page..

```
function getFav() {
    const x = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favemovies"));
    console.log(x);
    axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${x}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US`)
        .then((response) => {
            document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = response.data.map(item =>
                `  <div class="movie-card" id="mv">
            <img src="${IMG_URL+item.poster_path}" alt="movie poster" class="movie-poster">
            <div class="movie-info d-flex">
                <button type="button" class="btn-look btn-danger" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#detailCard" onclick="movieDeets(${item.id})">
                    Details
                  </button>
                 <div class="text-white p-1 float-end">
                 <a><i class="bi bi-bookmark" onclick="watchMenu(${item.id})"></i></a>
                 <a><i class="bi bi-heart" onclick="favMenu(${item.id})"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="detailCard" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="detailCard" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
      </div>
      </div>`


            ).join('')

        })
}
```

i keep getting this error instead..

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.data.map is not a function
    at main.js:173:70
```

Comment: You can convert to an array using something like this ```[array]``` or ```[...array]```. In this case possibly doing ```[response.data]``` should convert to an array. Without an example I cannot reproduce for you to help out better.

Comment: log your response, response.data should be an array.

Comment: @AidanDonnelly i'll try to apply that approach, thanks!

Comment: The issue seems unrelated to the localstorage contents, rather the response from ajax handling

Comment: Can you update post to include a log of what ```response``` contains?

Comment: you are sending JSON.parsed as a query string, that might be an issue and you are not getting the correct response from the server. show an example what your api expects and what is in local storage. (example only)